# Jquery Modal Inputs Appears Before Loading Data

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, loading

I am using a jquery Modal to open forms and edit data. These forms are being loading with Ajax (Load Method).

What happens is that the window with the fields appear as an empty form, and only after a while the data is loaded.

I think it is something related with cache. Is that correct? How can I resolve this?

Here's the code:

```
var janelaModal;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.lnkModalAddOption').each(function () {
        PrepareModal($(this), false);
    });

    $('.lnkModalAddOption').live("mouseenter", function () {
        PrepareModal($(this), false);
    });

    $(".linkAcaoModal").live("click", function () {
        PrepareModal($(this), true);
    });

});

function PrepareModal(objetoClick, show) {

    idModal = "modalAddLineTable";

    var titleToShow = objetoClick.attr("Funcionalidade");
    var urlToLoad = objetoClick.attr("href");

    if ($("#" + idModal).length == 0) {
        $("#Modais").append("");
    }
    else {
        $("#" + idModal).html("Carregando...");
    }


    $("#" + idModal)
        .load(urlToLoad)
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 'auto',
            modal: true,
            title: titleToShow
        });

    if (show == true) {
        ShowModal($("#" + idModal));
    }
    else {
        objetoClick.live("click", function () {
            ShowModal($("#" + idModal));
        });
    }
}

function ShowModal(objetoModal) {
    janelaModal = objetoModal;

    if (janelaModal != "") {
        janelaModal.dialog("open");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post the code you currently have.  Any of the jQuery you've written, as well as HTML.

Comment: You might have to use `.ready()` http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: You are most likely showing the dialogue before load has completed. `load` has a callback method you should be using and show the modal within that. This is an absolute guess though as you have posted no code at all. Please post the relevant scripts so we  can have a closer look.